# When I copied photos from my camera to my desktop, they have fragmented equally throughout the remainder of my hard drive. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, defragment

A couple of days ago I copied 200 or so CR2 photos from my DSLR Canon EOS 1000D to a folder on my Desktop.

Today when I opened up my defrag program it shows that 1 or 2 images has been scattered in blocks almost equally throughout the remainder of my hard drive, as you can see at the bottom of the blocks in my screenshot. All that space was previously completely free.

That screenshot was taken after running a defrag.

I have two main questions:

1. Why have all these images been fragmented rather than copied into a single block?
2. Am I going to run into problems with large files if, even after defragmenting, the blocks remain as they are now?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First I have a question: where did you get this window? Ive done defreg so far but I havent seen this window! Start>All Programs>Accesories>SystemTools>Defreg[..] ?  
Second: No you will not have any problem in the future. Windows itself will take care of problems automatically.

Comment: @UltraDEVV Disk Defrag is an alternative defragmentation software made by Auslogics.

Comment: Nicer than stock windows one ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects of defragmentation:

- removing multiple fragments from files, so that each exists in a contiguous area of disc;
- removing the fragmentation of free space to give a single block of free space.

Unfortunately, most defragmenters make a reasonable job of doing the first of these, but in the process often make free space fragmentation worse. New files are created in the free space, so they occupy a fragmented area and become fragmented themselves, as you have observed.

I'm afraid I have not yet found a defragmenter that makes a good job of both. Note that it is impossible to have a completely defragmented free space block, because certain files are immovable, and they will inevitably have adjacent free space.

Comment: The pattern that you can see at the bottom of the blocks was actually the same before I ran the defragmenter (sorry, I should have taken a 'before' screenshot too). The Windows defragmenter is scheduled for Wednesday 1am, and I copied those photos on a Saturday, so it can't have been that which has caused this issue. So it must be that the photos were fragmented as I copied them from my camera to my computer? But why would this happen?

Comment: I have used the Auslogics software in the past and it was OK, but it obviously did nothing to optimise free space; the best I found for free space was command-line based, but even that was not very good. How do you know that the scattered files are your photos? Was the free space in a large block before the up-load? I have no idea how Windows allocates new file space in NTFS partitions, nor whether the copy command you used would try to pre-allocate a file of the required size or simply create a zero-length file before copying data into it.

Comment: I can click each block and it will list out the files that are  currently occupying that block. Yes, the free space was in a large block before. I've never seen this behaviour before; this isn't the first time I've copied files from my camera to my Desktop. I've been using that HDD for almost 9 months and new files were always created in the next available block up until now.

Comment: That's what I would have expected to happen. I would try moving them off the disc, then back again after checking that the free space was in the large block, as previously. In looking around I found http://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-free-defragmentation-software-windows - that site says that Auslogics should optimise free space, but you may like to try one of the others. One thing I do know stops files being moved is when the "system" attribute is set. Any chance of that?

Comment: I checked Auslogics Defrag again today and the blocks are now arranged in a 'normal' fashion (i.e. in one large clump with the free space after). Not sure what caused this to happen. Maybe the scheduled Windows defrag software worked its magic in the background!

Comment: That's as good an explanation as any I can think of!